# Netsuite filter property SHOW FILTER IN FILTER REGION availability in saved searches

Tags: netsuite

I created a custom fee-form text field called 'Relation Id' and added it to all my sales type transactions. I set the display type to 'normal'.

Now I want to use this field to filter on in a saved search.

I added the field to my filters, but for some reason I cannot choose whether to use the filter on the UI (the field is greyed out/uneditable):
[image]

Could somehow explain what decides whether or not I am able to choose whether to show this field in the filter region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me this had to do with Netsuite storing some metadata regarding the report. I recreated the exact same report with the same result columns and the now this filter did actually have this field enabled for editing.

So if you change field properties of a field used in a saved search results and there is an error you can not explain, it may always be a good idea to recreate the saved search from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have selected Store Value check box in the body field.